# Ordering Main Model using Relationship Column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two Models named `Product` and `Merchant`.

Product contains basic data of a product and Product can have multiple Merchants.

Merchants contain pricing of each product, SKU, etc.

Now I want to order Products based on the First merchant price.

Merchants are always ordered by the lowest price first for each product.

```
Product::with('merchants')
->whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($highlight) {
    $q->where('id', $highlight->category_id);
})
->orderBy('merchants.price', 'asc')
->get();
```

For example, this is the output of the above query without using `orderBy`.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Product Name"
    "merchants" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "price" => 4756
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Another Product"
    "merchants" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "price" => 100
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "price" => 200
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Now how can I order products based on First Merchant price?
For example Product with an ID of 3 should come in the first place because it has the lowest price of 100.

I tried joining the merchants with product but because there can be more than 1 merchant, products get cloned itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution ;)

```
$products = Product::with('merchants')
    ->whereHas('category', fn ($q) => $q->where('id', $highlight->category_id))
    ->select('products.*')
    ->join('merchants', 'merchants.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderByRaw('MIN(merchants.price)')
    ->get();
```

Comment: If you run mysql in strict mode this query will have a lot of columns missing